# fail2ban : read whitelist from a database

Tags: fail2ban

Now I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I try it.

I have a fail2ban running on my server.
And I have a whitelist called **ignoreip** in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`(I is a list of IPs and masks)

I have one nice questions:

- is there a way or a plugin for fail2ban to use a database table instead of the **ignoreip** list?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, there is a way.

Fail2ban has an `ignorecommand` parameter, that you could use to check against SQL database.
[Here is an example using sqlite](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2013#issuecomment-426940189).

Note: there is parameter `ignorecache`, which makes it fast and minimizes load (overhead to check on every failure), but it is relative "fresh" - it was released firstly in 0.10.4 and 0.11.1.